# Nested JSON data accessing elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I use console.log(responseJSON) and it prints this logs to screen as below code. So I want to print only latlng and when I try to console.log(responseJSON.markers.latlng) or with console.log(responseJSON.markers) then it prints undefined.

```
Array [
Object {
  "markers": Object {
    "index": "1",
    "latlng": Object {
      "latitude": "40.3565",
      "longitude": "27.9774",
    },
  },
},
Object {
  "markers": Object {
    "index": "3",
    "latlng": Object {
      "latitude": "40.3471",
      "longitude": "27.9598",
    },
  },
},
Object {
  "markers": Object {
    "index": "2",
    "latlng": Object {
      "latitude": "40",
      "longitude": "27.9708",
    },
  },
},]
```

How can I print and get data printed e.g. with:

```
console.log(responseJSON.markers.latlng);
```

Comment: Your response is an array, not a single object. `responseJSON[0].markers` will work.

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://json.org). _"JSON is a textual, language-indepedent data-exchange format, much like XML, CSV or YAML."_ - [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response is an array. You have to use an index to get to each of the elements of the array.

For instance responseJSON[0].markers.latlong, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the inner contents of an array of object with simple [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop

```js
var responseJSON= [
 {
  "markers":  {
    "index": "1",
    "latlng":  {
      "latitude": "40.3565",
      "longitude": "27.9774",
    },
  },
},
 {
  "markers":  {
    "index": "3",
    "latlng":  {
      "latitude": "40.3471",
      "longitude": "27.9598",
    },
  },
},
 {
  "markers":  {
    "index": "2",
    "latlng":  {
      "latitude": "40",
      "longitude": "27.9708",
    },
  },
},];

responseJSON.forEach(function(currentElement){
   console.log(currentElement.markers.latlng)
})
```